# What is this just-hatched black caterpillar with white and black hairs, found in India?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification, india, caterpillars

Can anyone tell me which caterpillar this is? Its body looks black and it has 
hairs that are white and black, with a little bit of brown.

It was on a utensil which was kept in a dark place. I watched it come out from the cocoon on the left after my mother poured water on it, then it tried to climb the walls of the utensil.

I live in Punjab in the northern part of India, which is in Asia. 
It was about 5cm long but i couldn't measure the actual length. Now it is gone.

But i will try to find another one of these around my home. If i can i will put a picture of it on this site.

[image: caterpillar in a metal pan]

And it came out of cocoon so is it even a caterpillar? I think caterpillars make cocoons to become moths and butterflies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does seem to be 'Outdoors'

Comment: @JanDoggen it's on par with most of our other identification questions, we keep old pans out in the greenhouse so can't see this as being off topic :)

Comment: If you want any more details just ask

Comment: Do you have an estimate of size and any other pictures?

Comment: This isn't enough for an answer, but it looks like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycs_YtAcYWA), which I found by Googling hairy caterpillars, India.  (Anyone: feel free to use this comment as a starting point.)  There are also Google links on identifying hairy caterpillars, which I do not have time to research.  The size of your caterpillar will be important.